# qwtPlot::print function not available in qwt-6.1.2

Tags: qpixmap, qwt

I tried to export the current graph into a pixmap image. i checked some implementation using

QwtPlotPrintFilter

```
QwtPlotPrintFilter filter;
    int options = QwtPlotPrintFilter::PrintAll;
d_plot->print(pixmap, filter);
```

but im not able to find **QwtPlot::Print(** function or **QwtPlotPrintFilter**. is there any alternate functinality available or problem with version i downloaded.

or i have to use **QwtPlotRenderer** ?